# lineinfile module in ansible not updating all changes

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make 2 different changes in one file  but only last change is getting updated ... Looks like ansible holds the file in memory (after first change) and never dump it back to disk as it knows there is/are  more change (s) to be made as per .yml file. so when it is making  second change in same file (but the one on disks ) and while processing it , older file in memory is getting replaced with newer version. So first change was done but never closed/completed/dumped back to disk.

There should be some mechanism to 'close' the file after each change but did not see it on ansible docs. Anyone aware?

i noticed same kind of change can be looped but doesn't accept different 2 different types of changes.

P.S. - The same be accomplished by using different tasks but i don't want to use (may need 15-20 changes in a file so don't want same number fI am trying to make 2 different changes in one file  but only last change is getting updated ... Looks like ansible holds the file in memory (after first change) and never dump it back to disk as it knows there is/are  more change (s) to be made as per .yml file. so when it is making change (second)  in the same file (but on disks ) and while processing it , file in memory is getting replaced with newer version. So first change was done but never closed/completed/dumped back to disk.

There should be some mechanism to 'close' the file after each change but did not see it on ansible docs. Anyone aware?
first change- insert a text in file.
second change- replace a text in the same file.

P.S. - The same be accomplished by using different tasks but i don't want to use (may need 15-20 changes in a file so don't want same number of tasks)of tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on the same file, you'll need to run the playbook with `--forks=1` or `-f 1` as in:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --forks=1
```

The default is 5 forks (or whatever you have set in your ansible.cfg). Those forks can overwrite each other's changes.